# American or British Animated Kids Movie About an Alien War

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

**What I know:**

- The characters spoke English
- It was 3D animated
- The title was one word
- I saw it in 2011, give or take a year, but I believe it was at least a year old when I watched it
- It was Sci-Fi and involved at least one race of semi-humanoid aliens
- The setting was not Earth

**What I'm confident about:**

- It involves a war, possibly a civil war, between one race of aliens and another, or aliens and humans
- The title has "tri" in it
- There were battles using small spaceships for individuals, bubblish, possibly with bio-mechanical wings
- At one point the protagonist race doesn't realize that the antagonists wish them harm, and one unimportant character stands on top of a building shouting at the spaceships flying above, saying "Take me with you!" to which the antagonists beamed her up and apparently killed her
- The setting was a bright planet with a white gaseous surface above which the buildings floated

**What might be true:**

- The plot involves a baby female alien who is separated from her own race and becomes part of a second race of aliens who raise her as their own. The major conflict ensues when she grows up, and her original race attacks the race that is now her family (maybe they assume kidnapping?)
- It had a touching climax and a love-story subplot

Comment: Welcome to the community, nice first post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has many aspects in common with [***Terra***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0858486/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl) also known as *The Battle for Terra* (2007)

> A peaceful alien planet faces annihilation, as the homeless remainder of the human race sets its eyes on Terra. Mala, a rebellious Terrian teenager, will do everything she can to stop it.